# $X^ tX$ of dataset

Tags: regression, linear

I have the data set

[image]

which is used with the model $y = Xb+e$

How can I find $X^t X$?

I worked it out the matrix to be:

$\begin{bmatrix}11&0&1\\0&6&0\\1&0&5\end{bmatrix}$

is this correct?

Comment: Do you know what the matrix $X$ is in this situation?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix, make sure to read through the Multiple Regression section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X\,transpose\,X$ is key in the linear regression. $X$ is called the *model matrix*, and consists of the values of the *regressors* (or independent variables) - with $y$ being the *regressand* or dependent variable.

In your example, $X$ is a bit surprising with only $1$, $-1$ and $0$, and perhaps a linear OLS model may not be optimal, but just in the interest of lending you a hand with this, the model matrix would be:

```
   (Intercept) x1 x2
1            1  1  0
2            1  0  1
3            1 -1  0
4            1  0 -1
5            1  1  0
6            1  0  1
7            1 -1  0
8            1  0 -1
9            1  1  0
10           1  0  1
11           1 -1  0
```

The $X^tX$ amounts to:

```
            (Intercept) x1 x2
(Intercept)          11  0  1
x1                    0  6  0
x2                    1  0  5
```

So, there you have it... I think you are right.

Comment: +1 We can obtain this matrix by inspection of the original predictors without any multiplication required: there are 11 observations, so the $1,1$ element is obviously 11. $x_1$ and $x_2$ consist only of $0$ and $\pm1$, so for their diagonal you simply count the non-zero terms. For the $1,2$ element there are as many +1 as -1 terms in $x_1$ so it must be $0$; for the $1,3$ element there's one fewer -1 than +1 in $x_2$, so it will be $1$, and for the $2,3$ element there's always a 0 element in either $x_1$ or $x_2$ with each non-zero in the other, so it's $0$.